Few doubts about "A new elementary proof of the Prime Number Theorem" by Richter
I'm working on Richter's "A new elementary proof of the Prime Number Theorem" paper.
I have some doubt about the proof of proposition 3.1
Here's the reference to the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.03255.
What I found not clear is the bound at the beginning of p.7:
Lemma 3.3 (applied with $\sigma = 2$) gives the estimate:
$$\bigg|P \cap\left(\frac{8^x}{2^{n+1}}, \frac{8^x}{2^n}\right]\bigg| \leq \frac{8^x}{2^{n+1}x}  + O(1).$$
It is clearly not the direct application of Lemma 3.3 and I'm not sure how to get this bound starting from the one that Lemma 3.3 actually gives.
Bonus: it's less relevant to me at the moment but I'm also struggling to understand how the term $O(1/N)$ arises in the first equality in “Proof of Theorem 1.1 assuming Proposition 2.2.” at p.4.

as for the second question my feeling is that it has nothing to do with the Proposition $2.2$ itself but just replacing the index of summation from $n \le [N/q]$ to $n \le N, q |n$ and seeing what error we get given that $|g| \le 1$ and the various definitions of the projections $\mathbb E$ - that's where I would look

That’s my idea too, and I tried to do as you suggest but it didn’t get me the desired O(1/N).

I will look a bit later and see what happens

Thank you again. Let me know if there are any updates

Here I think the author skips an intermediate step as for $n \le x-1$ actually Lemma $3.3$ indeed applies directly as the $\log \frac{8^x}{2^{n+1}}=3x\log 2 - (n+1)\log 2 \ge 2x\log 2$ while $\beta(2)=2\log 2$ so the given inequality holds, namely: $$\bigg|P \cap\left(\frac{8^x}{2^{n+1}}, \frac{8^x}{2^n}\right]\bigg| \leq \frac{(2\log 2) 8^x}{2^{n+1}x(3x\log 2-(n+1)\log 2)}  + O(1) \leq\frac{8^x}{2^{n+1}x}  + O(1).$$
For $n \ge x$ we can use that the number of primes is at most the length of the interval giving us a $4^x$ total in $(1,4^x]$ which is $o(8^x/x)$ so the bound obtained is $$\bigg|P \cap\left(8^x,8^{x+1}]\right]\bigg| \geq \frac{8 \times 8^x}{3x+3}-\frac{8^x}{x}(1+o(1))  + O(1) \geq \frac{8^x}{x}$$

thank you very much. Any idea about the bonus question?

see my comment above - try that and see if it works
